# PowerShell - Compare between 2 sizes of files and return true only if the change is up to 10%

Tags: powershell

I have a script that get the size of each file in KB, I want to return true only if the delta between them up to 10% (up or down)

Example1:

```
$file1 = 100 KB
$file2 = 110 KB
```

In this case I need to get true

Example2:

```
$file1 = 90 KB
$file2 = 110 KB
```

This should return false

What I have got so far:

```
$size1 = ($file1 = Get-Item -Path 'C:\Intel\file1.sql').length/1024 
$size2 = ($file2 = Get-Item -Path 'C:\Intel\file2.sql').length/1024


$DifferenceCount = $size1 - $size2 +1
$percentageDifference = $DifferenceCount / $size1 * 100

    if(($percentageDifference -ge 10) -or ($percentageDifference -le -10))
{
    Write-Host "Percentage difference is bigger than +/-10%"
}
else {write-host "Percentage difference is less than +/-10%"}
```

What is the right formula to calculate the diff in %?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code.

Comment: Well, I am not right now with the time to come up with the whole script but you can for sure create a simple comparison of the file sizes and then run a conditional where if the delta is less than 10% it returns true, but like @Olaf said, we would need some code of yours to work on.

Comment: Don't know how to start...

Comment: Hey @Bandit you sent your comment after I sent mine, you can start with, https://www.spguides.com/check-file-size-using-powershell/ 
Using (get-file $file1).length and the $file2 equivalent, and then get the difference between the two as a percentage (I'd google that math operation to be sure) and if it's less than 10 (use PS comparison operators) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2 you can then say if that delta between $file1 and $file2 is -lt 10% return True.

Comment: Thank I will start and write my script for help

Comment: Great, I'll follow this question, so comment here if you get stuck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a small reusable helper function like below for that.

This will return the difference in (not rounded) percentage between two file sizes as positive double number.

```
function Get-SizeDifference {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [string]$Path1,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [string]$Path2
    )

    $size1 = (Get-Item -Path $Path1).Length
    $size2 = (Get-Item -Path $Path2).Length

    # avoid divide by zero
    if ($size1 -eq 0 -and $size2 -eq 0) { return 0 }
    if ($size1 -eq 0 -or $size2 -eq 0)  { return 100 }

    # you can get the size INCREASE from $size1 to $size2 using (could be a negative number)
    # ($size2 - $size1) / $size1 * 100

    # or the size DECREASE from $size1 to $size2 using (could be a negative number)
    # ($size2 - $size1) / $size2 * 100

    # however, to get the AVERAGE size difference you do (always a positive number)
    $difSize = [math]::Abs($size1 - $size2)
    $average = ($size1 + $size2) / 2
    $difSize * 100 / $average
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
if ((Get-SizeDifference 'C:\Intel\file1.sql' 'C:\Intel\file2.sql') -gt 10) {
    Write-Host "Percentage difference is more +/-10%"
}
else {
    write-host "Percentage difference is less than +/-10%"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good start to solve your comparison question.

You've got to calculate the different using some math.

```
#!/usr/bin/env powershell

#get the two files
$hassize = '{0}.name has a size of {1} KB'
$file1 = Get-Item -Path "$env:HOMEDRIVE/test.csv"
$file2 = Get-Item -Path "$env:HOMEDRIVE/jedurham_login_events.csv"

#measure their individual sizes
Write-Output -InputObject ($hassize -f $file1.name,($file1.Length/1KB))
Write-Output -InputObject ($hassize -f $file2.name,($file2.Length/1KB))

##calculate the size difference
$diff =[math]::Round(($file1.Length - $file2.Length) / ($file1.Length) * 100)
Write-Output -InputObject ("That's a {0}% difference!" -f $diff)
```

Now that you've calculated the difference you can use an `if/else` loop to determine the output.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env powershell

#get the two files
$hassize = '{0}.name has a size of {1} KB'
$file1 = Get-Item -Path "$env:HOMEDRIVE/test.csv"
$file2 = Get-Item -Path "$env:HOMEDRIVE/jedurham_login_events.csv"

#measure their individual sizes
Write-Output -InputObject ($hassize -f $file1.name,($file1.Length/1KB))
Write-Output -InputObject ($hassize -f $file2.name,($file2.Length/1KB))

##calculate the size difference
$diff =[math]::Round(($file1.Length - $file2.Length) / ($file1.Length) * 100)
Write-Output -InputObject ("That's a {0}% difference!" -f $diff)

if ($diff -gt 10)
{
    ####################################################################################
    ##
    ## the above is using the '-gt' comparison operation
    ## to check if $diff is greater than 10%
    ##
    ## this is part of the script where we would define
    ## what we want to happen if the comparison is evaluatd as true
    ## or in this case
    ##
    ## if the percentage of difference between file1 and file2 is GREATER THAN 10
    ##
    ## the calculation being used is 
    ##
    ## percentage difference = ((a - b) / (a) * 100) 
    ##



    Write-Output -InputObject ('The percentage difference is {0}. Which is bigger than 10!' -f $diff)

    ## Move-Item -Path $file1 -Destination 'path/if/true'

}
Else{

    ## this is where we would put commands if the comparison
    ## is evaluated as false


    Write-Output -InputObject ('The percentage difference is {0}. Which is smaller than 10!' -f $diff)

    ## Move-Item -Path $file1 -Destination 'path/if/false'
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. @another victim of the mouse, It look like the script return always 200% diff. In addition I need to convert the sizes to KB

Comment: How can I get true or false when $diff is bigger than 10% or smaller from 10% ?

Comment: The result is always 
The percentage difference is 200. Which is bigger than 10!
No meter what the sizes of the files

Comment: Can you see my update script in the question and tell me if I can use it please?
I want to know if its good

Comment: But I get a correct answer..how? Maybe you can correct it for me please?

Comment: Don’t understand the /2

Comment: According to your answer the formula is 100 * |a - b| / ((a + b) / 2)
the result for a=15 and b=10 is 40% and its wrong....

Comment: For a=15 and b=10 my formula gave the same results
(a-b +1) / a * 100

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245112/discussion-between-another-victim-of-the-mouse-and-bandit).

Answer (score 2):

The most basic solution would be something like this:

```
$file1 = 100KB
$file2 = 110KB

if ($file2 -ge ($file1 * 1.1)) {
    "file2 is at least 10% bigger than File1"
}
```